# WARNING 000632: datum conflict when creating buffer in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, buffer, datum

A buffer I created successfully executed, but I received the following message in ArcGIS Desktop 10:

> WARNING 000632: Datum conflict between map and output.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't really a big deal, just a minor warning from ArcGIS. If you want it to go away, change the spatial reference for your data frame to match that of your output feature class. More info:  [000632 : Datum conflict between map and output.](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00vp0000001v000632.htm)

Docs on how to change your data frame's spatial reference:  [Specifying a coordinate system](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00660000000v000000.htm)

Comment: From first link -- "layer is automatically transformed to the data frame's coordinate system." I interpret this to mean that my layer and data frame match up in the map display. Is this accurate?

Comment: Also: will I run into problems running intersect and union functions if the coordinate systems are off?

Comment: ArcGIS automatically reprojects data on the fly so that they can be displayed in the same coordinate system. The underlying data isn't actually transformed.

Comment: Best practice would be to make sure all your inputs for intersect, union, etc. are in the same coordinate system but ArcGIS will transform them on the fly.

Comment: Systematic testing in ArcView 9.1 uncovered *loads* of bugs in computing spatial relationships between polygon layers whenever they had an undefined coordinate system.  Most of the bugs went away once a coordinate system was defined.  I haven't checked whether those bugs have been fixed in subsequent releases.  It's prudent to view all geoprocessing operations with suspicion.

Comment: @whuber: Can't say I'm surprised...you'll save yourself some time and headaches by making sure all your data used in various analyses is in the same coordinate system.